# React Spring useTransition renders first item three times

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

Having a problem with `useTransition`, console logging transitions is outputting **Menu** three times instead *Menu1*, *Menu2*, *Menu3*

**Ttransition.map** also renders **Menu1** three times

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([{ text: 'Menu1'}, { text: 'Menu2'}, { text: 'Menu3'}]);

const transitions = useTransition(items, item => item, {
        from: { transform: 'translate3d(0,-40px,0)', opacity: '0' },
        enter: { transform: 'translate3d(0,0px,0)', opacity: '1'},
        leave: { transform: 'translate3d(0,-40px,0)', opacity: '0'},
    })

return ( 
    <Menu style={animatonmenu}>
        <ul>
        {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) =>
            <animated.li key={key} style={props} onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>{item.text}</animated.li>
        )}
        </ul>
    </Menu>
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [documentation on useTransition](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-transition) the problem seems to be this part:

```
const transitions = useTransition(items, (item) => item, {
    from: { transform: "translate3d(0,-40px,0)", opacity: "0" },
    enter: { transform: "translate3d(0,0px,0)", opacity: "1" },
    leave: { transform: "translate3d(0,-40px,0)", opacity: "0" }
});
```

Instead of doing `(item) => item` you should do `(item) => item.key`. Because otherwise react-spring is probably not able to uniquely identify each item.

So instead you should do something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { key: 1, text: "Menu1" },
    { key: 2, text: "Menu2" },
    { key: 3, text: "Menu3" }
  ]);

  const transitions = useTransition(items, (item) => item.key, {
    from: { transform: "translate3d(0,-40px,0)", opacity: "0" },
    enter: { transform: "translate3d(0,0px,0)", opacity: "1" },
    leave: { transform: "translate3d(0,-40px,0)", opacity: "0" }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
          <animated.li key={key} style={props}>
            {item.text}
          </animated.li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```